# Blazor code syntax background color highlighting visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image: Highligt image example]

I have been trying to find the setting in visual studio where I can remove the obnoxious background-color highlighting in a Blazor components' `@code {}` section. What setting do I have to kill to remove this behaviour in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors. Scroll for HTML Razor Code Background, select it and as an Item background choose Custom. Select rgb(30, 30, 30) to match your editor background and make it invisible.

Comment: Thanks so much! I would instead though change it to "Automatic" so it matches with your theme